# How to create a list of string from columns values in a dataframe

Tags: julia

I have this dataframe:

```
Text     feat1   feat2   feat3    feat4
string1    1       1       0        0
string2    0       0       0        1
string3    0       0       0        0
```

I want to create 2 other columns this way:

```
Text     feat1   feat2   feat3    feat4     all_feat            count_feat
string1    1       1       0        0       ["feat1","feat2"]       2
string2    0       0       0        1       ["feat4"]               1
string3    0       0       0        0       []                      0
```

What's the best approach to do it in Julia?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one of possible ways to do it:

```
julia> df
3×5 DataFrame
 Row │ Text     feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4
     │ String   Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ string1      1      1      0      0
   2 │ string2      0      0      0      1
   3 │ string3      0      0      0      0

julia> transform(df,
                 AsTable(r"feat") =>
                 ByRow(x -> [string(k) for (k,v) in pairs(x) if v == 1]) =>
                 :all_feat,
                 r"feat" => (+) => :count_feat)
3×7 DataFrame
 Row │ Text     feat1  feat2  feat3  feat4  all_feat            count_feat
     │ String   Int64  Int64  Int64  Int64  Array…              Int64
─────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │ string1      1      1      0      0  ["feat1", "feat2"]           2
   2 │ string2      0      0      0      1  ["feat4"]                    1
   3 │ string3      0      0      0      0  String[]                     0
```

Comment: Thanks @Bogumil.  One question: What if the columns names are random strings  and not feat1,feat2,feat3?  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: @merchmallow If the only column you want to ignore is "Text", and all the rest are features, you can do `Not(:Text)` instead of `r"feat"` in the code above.

Comment: or `Not(1)` if you want to exclude the first column.

Comment: As an additional note, if you have very many columns then instead of `r"feat" => (+) => :count_feat` use `AsTable(r"feat") => ByRow(sum) => :count_feat` as it will be more efficient and put less strain on Julia compiler.